# Скрин сайта

Tags: поиск, веб-программирование

Насколько я знаю, есть какая-то программа/скрипт/еще что-то (простите, не знаю, как сформулировать), которая заходит на сайт по ссылке и делает что-то вроде скрина страницы, Потом эти скрины используется для создания портфолио работ, например, как это сделано  [здесь](http://netcat.ru/ordersite/partners/timedesign.html). Что это за программа?

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что эта программа называется `PrintScreen`.

Comment: нет, у них, насколько я знаю, есть какая-то программа, которая обходит сайты по ссылкам, которые им присылают, и делает снимок страницы. ну, мне так объяснили. хочу вот выяснить, что это такое и как оно работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я делаю скрины через [fireshot](http://screenshot-program.com/downloads.php):

> FireShot является аддонон для Firefox, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Seamonkey и Thunderbird, который создает и редактирует скриншоты веб-страниц.

Comment: большое спасибо, хорошая вешь

Answer (score 1):

ну [вот например](http://browsershots.org/) с кучей браузеров/движков и ОС

Comment: но это, как я понимаю, больше для того чтобы посмотреть, как выглядит страница в разных браузерах?

Comment: да, именно так. конечно это более продвинутая версия принтсринилки ;)

Comment: тоже полезная вещь)